# AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request

Tags: web-services, soap, saml-2.0, wso2-as, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to build an application with a WSO2 Application server and Identity server.

the soap server which is based on Axis2 Framework needs to have WS-Trust based Authentication. For learning, I'm following this blog http://www.vitharana.org/2015/01/how-ws-trust-sts-works-in-wso2-identity.html

At the end when I run the sample application I get following error. Sample Application is from https://github.com/ajithnv/blog_resources/tree/master/sts-client

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.sts.Client.run(Client.java:176)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.sts.Client.main(Client.java:78)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:141)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
```

Comment: OP was this resolved ?

Comment: No, wasn't able to resolve. Still struggling.